# Importing within imports

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

I have the following program structure:

```
main.py
__init__.py
modules----------module1.py
                 module2.py
                 __init__.py
```

In `main.py` I import `module1.py`.
In `module1.py` I import `module2.py`.

When I run `main.py`, it says "error in `module1.py`, there is no `module2.py`".

However, when I run `module1.py` on its own, it works correctly. I do not understand this behaviour or how I can fix it.

NB: I am using "`from module1 import func`" without the `.py`.

Edit: In particular could someone explain what is going on behind the scenes differently when I run main.py and don't import versus when I run module1 and do import.

Comment: You wrote `from module import func`, where is module defined.. I don't see it in your hierarchy.

Comment: apologies, have made it clear

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the folder containing 
main.py to $PYTHONPATH.

Say you have the following folder structure 
project/

.          main.py/

--------**init**.py

------- Modules/

------------------  module1.py

Then in your terminal run 
export "$PYTHONPATH=path_to_project:$PYTHONPATH"

Comment: Is it possible to do this in a more general way in the actual program? I need my project to be transferable between computers, i.e. want to be able to move it into any directory and run it.

Comment: i thought adding __init__.py was enough to make it function like a package and making the PYTHONPATH business not needed.

Comment: @Tom As well as having the `__init__.py` files you need to put the folder containing the project into one of the folders in the python path (i.e., what you see when you print `sys.path`). So `if main.py` is in `myproject/` then `myproject/` must be in one of the  `sys.path` folders (don't add `myproject/` itself to  `sys.path`).

Comment: Ok, thanks. So would it be ok to add sys.path.insert(0, '$HOME/git/myproject/') at the top of main.py (and any other files I am executing? Would it be possible to add it in a more general way that didn't limit it to being in the home directory? Is $HOME  a robust way of specifying the home directory? It seems to work fine.

Comment: it *works?*, I wouldn't have thought that it would work at all

Comment: @Tom that's not really a good way to go about getting your project on the path. I wrote up an [example project](https://github.com/waynew/simplest-python-package) that you can install with pip (the best) or `python setup.py install`. Manual path manipulations are generally a bad idea - they're largely frangible and they'll probably break things in weird ways.